# How to apply Watermarking on Image using Meteor JS

Tags: meteor

i'm new to Meteor JS and i want to implement one functionality where i want Image Watermarking using Meteor JS.

Is there any functionality or some examples so that i can have some idea to implement it in my application?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can add a watermark class and apply some CSS styling to get the desired effect :

```
.watermark:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"Watermark";
  color:#fff;
  font-size:1.2em;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px black;
  bottom:10px;
  right:10px;
}
```

Comment: is it permanent or its temporary. i mean i want to apply watermark permanent so that if i download that image then  watermark should be applied in downloaded image.

Comment: You need to modify the image on the server to do this, and serve the modified version, you could use graphicsmagick for Node.JS (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm) but this is non-trivial.

Comment: but i'm using meteor. so what is the best package to do image watermarking when uploading images.